# ACTIVE Record Query to Fetch data from three associated models

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am a newbie to programming and rails.In my Rails app, I have models called users, listings, reservations.A user has_many listings and reservations.A listing has_many reservations and reservation belongs to a listing and user.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :listings
     has_many :reservations
    end

    class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :reservations
    end


    class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :listing
    end
```

I want to have a query to fetch all the reservations with the following details

```
 RESERVATIONS # | LISTING OWNER NAME  | LISTING OWNER EMAIL | LISTING OWNER PHONE | GUEST NAME | GUEST EMAIL | CLASS OF LISTING | YEAR OF LISTING | NIGHTLY RENTAL RATE OF LISTING| TOTAL RENTAL AMOUNT
```

schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",
    t.string   "fullname",   
    t.string   "phone_number"
    end  

 create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "vehicle_type",   
    t.string   "listing_name" ,            
    t.string   "make",                         
    t.string   "model",                        
    t.string   "year", 
    t.integer  "daily_rent",
    t.integer  "user_id"   
end

create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",  
     t.integer  "total",
     t.integer  "listing_id"
 end
```

As Listing Owner and Guest, both are users
All I could up with a simple SQL query to fetch all the reservation details with the guest email and phone along with listing details of the corresponding reservation

```
  select r.id , u.email, u.fullname ,l.listing_name,l.year,l.daily_rent,r.total  from reservations r , users u ,listings l where u.id = r.user_id and l.id = r.listing_id;
```

**1)** I am **unable** to extract the LISTING OWNER NAME | OWNER EMAIL | OWNER PHONE but I am **able** to get Guest NAME | GUEST EMAIL | GUEST PHONE.
How to fetch the LISTING OWNER details ??

**2)** How to write the above SQL query in rails Active Record so I can use that in a model or controller to fetch results ??

Any Help is highly Appreciated.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom foreign keys as well as names in order to retrieve records in a cleaner way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings, foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :reservations, foreign_key: :guest_id
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many   :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

With this redefinition of your models, now you can easily query them like so:

```
reservation = Reservation.find_by(id: 1)
owner = reservation.listing.owner
guest = reservation.guest
total = reservation.total

# 'owner' and 'guest' are User instances. So you can invoke any fields on them that are defined in the model
owner.email
owner.fullname
owner.phone_number
```

By the way, to support the above definitions, you have to run the following migration:

```
class AddReferencesInListingsAndReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :listings,     :user_id,    :integer
    remove_column :reservations, :user_id,    :integer
    remove_column :reservations, :listing_id, :integer

    add_reference :listings,     :owner, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
    add_reference :reservations, :guest, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
    add_reference :reservations, :listing
  end
end
```

which will result in the following schema:

```
create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "vehicle_type",   
  t.string   "listing_name" ,            
  t.string   "make",                         
  t.string   "model",                        
  t.string   "year", 
  t.integer  "daily_rent",
  t.integer  "owner_id"
  t.index    "owner_id",   name: "index_listings_on_owner_id"
end

create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "guest_id",  
  t.integer  "total",
  t.integer  "listing_id"
  t.index    "guest_id",   name: "index_listings_on_guest_id"
  t.index    "listing_id", name: "index_listings_on_listing_id"
end

add_foreign_key "listings",     "users", column: "owner_id"
add_foreign_key "reservations", "users", column: "guest_id"
add_foreign_key "reservations", "listings"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "listing owner" I assume you mean the user relation.

```
reservation = Reservation.find(id) # Retrieves the reservation
reservation.user # Retrieves the associated user object
reservation.user.fullname # Listing owner name...
```